# JEditorPane / JTextPane in MarqueePanel

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, marquee

I'm attempting to scroll text in a JFrame, and the text itself has hyperlinks in it using the [MarqueePanel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) class. It seems, however, that while the scrolling works correctly, the links are all in a fixed place.

I attempted using JEditorPane and JTextPane and while the look is correct, the hyperlinks don't seem to move at all. Is this something that can be accomplished?

Edit: Code is below - MarqueePanel class link is above.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{

    JFrame w = new JFrame("Marquee Test");
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    w.setSize(screenSize.width, (int) ((float) .04 * (float) screenSize.height));

    MarqueePanel mp = new MarqueePanel(22,2);

    JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", "<font size=28><nobr><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Test link number 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Test link number 2</a></font></nobr>");
    jep.setOpaque(false);
    jep.setEditable(false);
    jep.addMouseListener(mp);

    jep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    mp.add(jep);
    w.add(mp);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you done ? Maybe it could be useful

Comment: Added code to help - I can't seem to figure out which part is the issue.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a marqueePanel instead of a JScrollPane?

Comment: The idea is to have the text scroll automatically - basically like a ticker. Not via user input.

Answer (score 1):

The `Marquee Panel` was not designed to handle events since it just renders each component at a different location to give a scrolling effect.

Here is a version that attempts to translate the MouseEvent and redispatch the event back to the original component:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
 *  The MarqueePanelMouse is used to scroll components from the right edge of the
 *  panel to the left edge. Scrolling is continuous. To simulate the scrolling
 *  of text you can simply add a JLabel to the panel.
 *
 *  Various properties control the scrolling of the components on the panel.
 *  Changes to the properties are dynamic and will take effect the next time
 *  the components are scrolled.
 */
public class MarqueePanelMouse extends JPanel
    implements ActionListener, AncestorListener, WindowListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    protected boolean paintChildren;
    protected boolean scrollingPaused;
    protected int scrollOffset;
    protected int wrapOffset;

    private int preferredWidth = -1;
    private int scrollAmount;
    private int scrollFrequency;
    private boolean wrap = false;
    private int wrapAmount = 50;
    private boolean scrollWhenFocused = true;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor that sets both the scroll frequency and
     *  scroll amount to a value of 5.
     */
    public MarqueePanelMouse()
    {
        this(5, 5);
    }

    /**
     *  Create an AnimatedIcon that will continuously cycle with the
     * default (500ms).
     *
     *  @param component  the component the icon will be painted on
     *  @param icons      the Icons to be painted as part of the animation
     */
    public MarqueePanelMouse(int scrollFrequency, int scrollAmount)
    {
        setScrollFrequency( scrollFrequency );
        setScrollAmount( scrollAmount );
        setLayout( new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS) );
        addAncestorListener( this );
//      addMouseListener( this );
//      addMouseMotionListener( this );
    }

    /*
     *  Translate the location of the children before they are painted so it
     *  appears they are scrolling left to right
     */
    @Override
    public void paintChildren(Graphics g)
    {
        //  Need this so we don't see a flicker of the text before scrolling

        if (! paintChildren) return;

        //  Normal painting as the components scroll right to left

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(-scrollOffset, 0);
        super.paintChildren(g);
        g2d.translate(scrollOffset, 0);

        //  Repaint the start of the components on the right edge of the panel once
        //  all the components are completely visible on the panel.
        //  (Its like the components are in two places at the same time)

        if (isWrap())
        {
            wrapOffset = scrollOffset - super.getPreferredSize().width - wrapAmount;
            g2d.translate(-wrapOffset, 0);
            super.paintChildren(g);
            g2d.translate(wrapOffset, 0);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  The default preferred size will be half the size of the components added to
     *  the panel. This will allow room for components to be scrolled on and off
     *  the panel.
     *
     *  The default width can be overriden by using the setPreferredWidth() method.
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();

        d.width = (preferredWidth == -1) ? d.width / 2 : preferredWidth;

        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth()
    {
        return preferredWidth;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the preferred width on the panel. A value of -1 will cause the
     *  default preferred with size calculation to be used.
     *
     *  @param preferredWidth  preferred width of the panel in pixels
     */
    public void setPreferredWidth(int preferredWidth)
    {
        this.preferredWidth = preferredWidth;
        revalidate();
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll amount.
     *
     *  @return the scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public int getScrollAmount()
    {
        return scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll amount. The number of pixels to scroll every time
     *  scrolling is done.
     *
     *  @param scrollAmount  scroll amount in pixels
     */
    public void setScrollAmount(int scrollAmount)
    {
        this.scrollAmount = scrollAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll frequency.
     *
     *  @return the scroll frequency
     */
    public int getScrollFrequency()
    {
        return scrollFrequency;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scroll frequency. That is the number of times scrolling
     *  should be performed every second.
     *
     *  @param scrollFrequency  scroll frequency
     */
    public void setScrollFrequency(int scrollFrequency)
    {
        this.scrollFrequency = scrollFrequency;

        int delay = 1000 / scrollFrequency;
        timer.setInitialDelay( delay );
        timer.setDelay( delay );
    }

    /**
     *  Get the scroll only when visible property.
     *
     *  @return the scroll only when visible value
     */
    public boolean isScrollWhenFocused()
    {
        return scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the scrolling property for unfocused windows.
     *
     *  @param scrollWhenVisible  when true scrolling pauses when the window
     *                              loses focus. Scrolling will continue when
     *                              the window regains focus. When false
     *                              scrolling is continuous unless the window
     *                              is iconified.
     */
    public void setScrollWhenFocused(boolean scrollWhenFocused)
    {
        this.scrollWhenFocused = scrollWhenFocused;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap property.
     *
     *  @return the wrap value
     */
    public boolean isWrap()
    {
        return wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping property. Normal scrolling is such that all the text
     *  will scroll from left to right. When the last part of the text scrolls off
     *  the left edge scrolling will start again from the right edge. Therefore
     *  there is a time when the component is blank as nothing is displayed.
     *  Wrapping implies that as the end of the text scrolls off the left edge
     *  the beginning of the text will scroll in from the right edge. So the end
     *  and the start of the text is displayed at the same time.
     *
     *  @param wrap  when true the start of the text will scroll in from the right
     *              edge while the end of the text is still scrolling off the left
     *              edge. Otherwise the panel must be clear of text before
     *              will begin again from the right edge.
     */
    public void setWrap(boolean wrap)
    {
        this.wrap = wrap;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the wrap amount.
     *
     *  @return the wrap amount value
     */
    public int getWrapAmount()
    {
        return wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Specify the wrapping amount. This specifies the space between the end of the
     *  text on the left edge and the start of the text from the right edge when
     *  wrapping is turned on.
     *
     *  @param wrapAmount  the amount in pixels
     */
    public void setWrapAmount(int wrapAmount)
    {
        this.wrapAmount = wrapAmount;
    }

    /**
     *  Start scrolling the components on the panel. Components will start
     *  scrolling from the right edge towards the left edge.
     */
    public void startScrolling()
    {
        paintChildren = true;
        scrollOffset =  - getSize().width;

        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     *  Stop scrolling the components on the panel. The conponents will be
     *  cleared from the view of the panel
     */
    public void stopScrolling()
    {
        timer.stop();
        paintChildren = false;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     *  The components will stop scrolling but will remain visible
     */
    public void pauseScrolling()
    {
        if (timer.isRunning())
        {
            timer.stop();
            scrollingPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  The components will resume scrolling from where scrolling was stopped.
     */
    public void resumeScrolling()
    {
        if (scrollingPaused)
        {
            timer.restart();
            scrollingPaused = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y)
    {
        Point translated = getTranslatedPoint(x, y);

        for (Component c: getComponents())
        {
            if (c.getBounds().contains(translated))
                return c;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Point getTranslatedPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        int translatedX = x + scrollOffset;

        if (isWrap())
        {
            int preferredWidth = super.getPreferredSize().width;
            preferredWidth += getWrapAmount();
            translatedX = translatedX % preferredWidth;
        }

        return new Point(translatedX, y);
    }

//  Implement ActionListener

    /**
     *  Adjust the offset of the components on the panel so it appears that
     *  they are scrolling from right to left.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        scrollOffset = scrollOffset + scrollAmount;
        int width = super.getPreferredSize().width;

        if (scrollOffset > width)
        {
            scrollOffset = isWrap() ? wrapOffset + scrollAmount : - getSize().width;
        }

        repaint();
    }

//  Implement AncestorListener

    /**
     *  Get notified when the panel is added to a Window so we can use a
     *  WindowListener to automatically start the scrolling of the components.
     */
    public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e)
    {
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( this ).addWindowListener( this );
    }

    public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
    public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {}

//  Implement WindowListener

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
    {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused())
            resumeScrolling();
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
    {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        stopScrolling();
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
    {
        if (isScrollWhenFocused())
            pauseScrolling();
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
    {
        resumeScrolling();
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)
    {
        pauseScrolling();
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
    {
        startScrolling();
    }

//  Implement MouseMotionListener

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        redispatchMouseEvent(e);
    }

    private void redispatchMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int eventID = e.getID();

        Component component = getComponentAt( e.getX(), e.getY() );

        if (component == null) return;

        Point translatedPoint = getTranslatedPoint( e.getX(), e.getY() );
        Point componentPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, translatedPoint, component);
        System.out.println(eventID + " : " + componentPoint);

        MouseEvent me = new MouseEvent(
            component,
            e.getID(),
            e.getWhen(),
            e.getModifiers(),
            componentPoint.x,
            componentPoint.y,
            e.getClickCount(),
            e.isPopupTrigger()
        );

        component.dispatchEvent( me );
    }
/*
    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }
*/
}
```

This version has NOT been debugged or fully tested so it may work for you or it may not.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that the panel uses a BoxLayout to handle the addition of items. I can tell when the mouse hovers over the left side of the panel, there are links there before the actual painting happens.

Answer (score 0):

When using the JEditorPane did you set the EditorKit or the ContentType to handle HTML?  See below for a working example that scrolls hyperlinks just fine:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("URL Demo");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JEditorPane aJEditorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html;", "<HTML>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu nisi in mi finibus mollis. Vivamus aliquet nunc eu arcu tristique, sit amet consequat nisl hendrerit. Curabitur nec libero magna. Phasellus bibendum nulla at lobortis interdum. Maecenas in euismod turpis, eget sagittis velit. Sed cursus convallis neque et mattis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque id placerat dolor. Sed finibus lectus volutpat, fermentum augue non, mattis lectus. Suspendisse quis lorem lacinia, rutrum mi eget, tincidunt lorem. Nam ultricies purus orci, vel bibendum nunc mollis non.<BR><BR><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Link to Google</a><BR><BR>Praesent eu quam est. Mauris lacinia gravida congue. Morbi eros mauris, sodales eget lacus ac, tincidunt iaculis nulla. Quisque libero quam, pretium ac nulla in, porta maximus dui. Suspendisse semper ex sit amet enim mollis, a commodo mauris sagittis. Quisque efficitur porta quam, eu auctor enim lacinia vel. Mauris ut quam dolor. Proin et ipsum vulputate, ullamcorper metus id, vulputate ante. Sed vestibulum laoreet nisi. Etiam gravida enim turpis, vitae aliquet lectus dictum iaculis. Proin eu enim hendrerit, molestie sapien eu, faucibus felis. Suspendisse diam purus, ullamcorper non arcu ac, pulvinar cursus odio. Mauris lobortis, neque eu eleifend aliquet, nisl urna fermentum odio, id eleifend nunc ipsum quis tellus. Curabitur feugiat a erat vitae vehicula.<BR><BR>Vivamus vitae nunc nulla. Curabitur pharetra elit vel justo fermentum consequat. Ut sed commodo sem. Fusce non pharetra nulla. Ut sed ultricies purus, nec congue magna. Quisque a semper eros, sit amet tristique metus. Sed non porttitor libero. Sed sagittis turpis in tortor mattis fringilla. Cras tempor, mauris vel tristique ullamcorper, mi est blandit ante, ut congue est mauris vitae arcu. Aenean ut elit sit amet eros facilisis feugiat a at enim. Nulla facilisi. Nam nec lorem leo. Vivamus consequat lorem nulla, at finibus augue gravida ac. Aenean ornare, sem sit amet congue volutpat, ante ex viverra erat, in consequat dolor massa et neque. Praesent ultrices lectus sit amet nibh interdum, non varius ligula vehicula. Maecenas non nibh accumsan, ultrices nisl in, viverra tortor.<BR><BR>Donec sed lacus tincidunt, malesuada neque in, luctus mauris. Vivamus sit amet sollicitudin metus. Duis eu hendrerit neque, at molestie elit. Donec consectetur tempus est sed venenatis. Quisque suscipit, mi vitae tristique porttitor, purus nulla maximus mi, at suscipit diam urna eget mauris. Nulla facilisi. Nulla fringilla imperdiet eros nec tristique.<BR><BR>Duis gravida est in leo tempus, eget sollicitudin nulla scelerisque. Mauris ipsum felis, convallis viverra nisl sed, elementum rhoncus mi. Nam egestas ipsum augue, ut fringilla ipsum fermentum quis. Phasellus efficitur ultrices libero. Pellentesque sed sagittis nisl. Fusce sit amet ante ut lectus aliquam posuere vel in mi. Nulla tempor at ligula in auctor. Nullam erat odio, ullamcorper eu odio at, eleifend faucibus quam. Integer viverra sapien ac interdum congue. Cras tristique et ante ac hendrerit. Proin semper nulla dui.</HTML>");

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(aJEditorPane);
frame.add(pane);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: The problem isn't the scrolling - it's that the JEditorPane is on a MarqueePanel. See the code in the edit I made.